# Only last name and "see note above" for same reference in the bibliography with Chicago

Tags: biblatex, endnotes, biblatex-chicago

I would like to refer to a previous note in the reference when the same citation appears again. As it stands now, author name and title appears when the same reference is cited again. I would like a bibliography that looks something like this:

1. John Johnson, “A title,” A Journal 60 (2015): 70–95.
2. Jane Janesdaughter, Book title (Oxford, UK: Oxford University Press, 2010), 40; Johnson (see note 1 above).
3. Johnson (see note 1 above).
4. Ibid.
5. Chris Christopherson, “A title,” A Journal 60 (2000): 100–50.
6. Johnson (see note 1 above).

My `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,uniquename=false,firstinits=false,uniquelist=false,sortcites=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\bibliography{library.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-chicago` already has some of the necessary structure in place. We modify the `footcite:save` macro to always save the note when a work was first cited.
We then modify `cite:short:cms` to only print a title if there were more works by the same author (with the option `singletitle`) and let it print the note referring back to the full citation.
Unfortunately, `cite:short:cms` is quite long, so the code is not particularly compact.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,uniquename=false,firstinits=false,uniquelist=false,sortcites=false,singletitle]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\iffootnote}%
    not test {\ifciteseen}
  }%
  {\csxdef{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
    \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}%
  {}}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short:cms}{% was cite:short
  \usebibmacro{allshort+firstcite+xref}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{inreference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{reference}\OR%
    \ifentrytype{mvreference}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}\AND\NOT%
      \ifentrytype{periodical}}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\ifboolexpr{%
          not test {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}}%
          and
          ((
          test {\ifcitation}%
          and
          togl {cms@citejtabb}%
          )
          or
          (
          test {\ifbibliography}%
          and
          togl {cms@bibjtabb}%
          ))
        }%
        {\printfield[shortjournal]{shortjournal}\newcunit}%
        {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\newcunit}}%
      {}}%
    {\ifentrytype{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifciteidem}%
      and
      not test {\ifbibliography}%
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}%
      and
      not togl {cms@noidem}%
      and
      not togl {cms@headlessnote}%
    }%
    {\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}%
      \classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
        \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
        {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
          \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
        {\printnames{labelname}%\usebibmacro{choose+labelname}%
          \isdot\classicpunct}}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    (
    test {\ifentrytype{review}}%
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{suppperiodical}}%
    )
    and
    test {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reviewof}}%
    and
    togl {cms@citerel}%
  }%
  {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    \usebibmacro{related}}%
  {\ifsingletitle{}{%
   \ifboolexpr{%
      togl {cms@allshort}%
      or
      test {\ifbibliography}%
    }%
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
    {\printtext[cmshyperlink]{%
        \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}%
    \ifboolexpr{%
      test {\ifuniquework}%
      or
      test {\ifcsundef{cms@xfield}}%
    }%
    {}%
    {\setunit{\shortextrapunct}%
      \usebibmacro{shortnote+extrafield}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffootnote} and test {\ifciteseen}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
       \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
    {}}%:\thefield{entrytype}?
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{vizedom:related}
dolor\autocite{sigfridsson}
sit\autocite{sigfridsson}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]